# Windows Phone 8 USB communication

Tags: c++, usb, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, symbian

I would just like to know if it would be possible to communicate to external hardware through USB with a Windows Phone application. More specifically I would like to communicate with my 3d printer by simply porting an existing open-source C++ application. Do any of you know if this is possible and possibly have any information on how to do this. Possibly some api references.

Also if any of you know of a way to do this on a Symbian device, that would also help.

Comment: Your "3d"? We're not going to guess what that is. You're leaving out a LOT of necessary information.

Comment: Not knowing what it is your specifically trying to do, I am not sure I can help.  I haven't seen any 3rd party products to date (that I'm aware of) that communicate via USB with a Windows Phone (short of Microsoft's Windows Phone app).  However, I have seen some products out there that utilize the headphone jack for simple communication - e.g. Thermodo - http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/robocat/thermodo-the-tiny-thermometer-for-mobile-devices.  Maybe that's an option for your needs?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say a "3D Printer" not just "3d"

Answer (score 0):

There are no public APIs for using USB in this way (i.e. as a host device) on Windows Phone.